# How to use " in a String with a path?

Tags: c#

I have a String with a path in it.

It looks like this :

```
TaskManager = "RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");"
```

I want to use this string to compile with codedom, but I get an error saying "cant find Software\Microsoft......".

Is there anyway to replace the " with another char?

Comment: TaskManager = RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");

Comment: I want to use this string in a text resource that is going to be compiled. The registryKey.... must have " too.

Comment: how do you want to use this string later?

Comment: its going to be compiled with codedom

Comment: well if it says that he can't find Software\microsoft etc... the problem is not the quotes but the fact that he cant find software\microsoft\ etc

Comment: What's the **actual** error?

Comment: When I write it like this : TaskManager = "RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(\"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System\");";               I get the Unrecognized escape sequence error.

Comment: Doing it with "" doesnt even work, It says 12 } are missing

Comment: Oh ok, i get it now, that's because you had to pass the right string to be written inside the method call using \" you were writing "software\microsoft\etc" while you had to write "software\\microsoft\\etc" so you either use @""software\\microsoft\\etc"" or \"software\\\\microsoft\\\\etc\" the problem was not with the quotes itself but with the slashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use verbatim string literal for paths so I don't have to double the backslashes:

```
TaskManager = @"RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(""Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"");"
```

`"` is doubled `""`

Comment: In this type of string, you don't have to double them. If you do, the resulting string will have double backslashes.

Comment: Sir Now I have another problem. It worked one time,now it doesnt. I  get this error : Invalid expression term '['

Comment: Please give us the new string you're trying to use.

Answer (score 2):

to write " inside a string use \"

```
String str= "my string with \"quotes\""; // my string with "quotes"
```

the character \ is used to write special character inside a string for example a \t write inside the string a tab and \n make the string go to a new line

or

```
String str= @"my string with ""quotes"""; //same as before
```

the character @ before a string make the compiler take the string as is, every special character is written without having to use \ before it, the only character that need to be escaped are the quotes itself that you write by doubling them ""

Watch out that iff you use the method with @ your \ \ in the path become \

Comment: got an unrecognized escape sequence when I do this : TaskManager = "RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(\"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System\");";

Comment: I want to write this string to the resource text file. That resource text file is saved as a string. I want to replace a /*line/* in this string with another string (see that one I posted above). The string (which contains the edited resource) is going to be compiled

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to escape the qoute then do something like this:

```
TaskManager = "RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(\"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System\");"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it this way

```
TaskManager = "RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey('Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System');"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use \"

to get a double quote, the same way as you used \ to get a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

```
TaskManager = "RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(\"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System\");"
```

That should fix it.